# javascript number pattern print

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to print the below pattern using javascript

```
n = 4

1
2 5
3 6 8
4 7 9 10
```

I tried the below code but it print the incremental number in row

```js
const pattern = (n) => {
  let count = 1;
  for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
      document.write(count + " ");
      count++;
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
};

pattern(4);
```

but the expectation is to print incremental number in col

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost on goal... try this:

```js
    const pattern = (n) => {
      for (let row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        let currentNum = row;
        let printRow = "";
       
        for (let j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
          printRow += currentNum + " ";
          currentNum += (n - j) ;
        }
        console.log(printRow);
      }
    };
    
    pattern(4);
```

and as your example
instead of `console.log` you can do

```js
    document.write(printRow + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = 1;var a={},n=4;
  for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (let col = row+1; col <=n; col++) {
        if(!a[col]){
            a[col]='';
        }
      a[col]+= count + ' ';
      count++;
    }
    console.log(a[row+1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let arr = [];
  let val = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = val;
      val++;
    }
  }

  let output = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      output += arr[j][i - j] + " ";
    }
    output += "\n";
  }

  console.log(output);
}

printIncrementalColumn(5);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).